# Перенести ядро фреймворка yii

Tags: php-frameworks, php, yii

Привет.
Есть папкак с ядром фремворка Yii,которая содержит папки framework ,requirements.
стала необходимость перенести их и сменить название директории содержащих их.

Какие настройки нужно провести ,чтобы не создавать новый сервер?
Поменять путь

```
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../Yi/framework/yii.php';
```

достаточно будет?

*Подскажите как выговарить название этого фреймворка по - русски?*

Comment: > Подскажите как выговарить название этого фреймворка по - русски?
я обычно называю [уии]

Comment: Кстати, кому интересно, он расшифр. как Yes it is

Comment: я называю юй =)

Comment: mountpoint ха-ха-ха.Зачет

Comment: я незываю его юии

Comment: ====       йии           ===

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна только папка framework, в ней и лежит Yii.
Если Вы его переносите, то достаточно поменять путь в index.php

Comment: Ну и, в yiic.php тоже)